# iText - Add text to existing landscape document

Tags: itext

In my project, I am opening existing PDFs and add text on it at specific positions. This worked well since today where I got a landscape file. This is my code:

```
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file + "_out.pdf");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
stamper.setRotateContents(true);
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(1);

ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas,
    Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("Text"), xPosition, yPosition, 0);

stamper.close();
reader.close();
outputStream.close();
```

When I opened the newly created file, the content is shown in portrait mode.

How do I have to change the code in order to get the file in landscape mode, together with the stamped text?

The file in question: http://www.share-online.biz/dl/RO1IPFVM0JX

Comment: Please provide the PDF in question. That been asked for, though, there is no 100% proof method to find the correct direction because in the content you can print rotated by any angle you want.

Comment: I added a link to the file in question. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: I just tested your code but the result PDF was displayed in landscape format. Furthermore I looked at the actual changes, and none of them would change a display orientation. Thus, the cause of your issue is something else. Which version of iText do you use? I used 5.4.4, a fairly recent version. Which PDF viewer do you use? I use Adobe Reader XI, Adobe Acrobat 9.5, and Foxit Reader 3.1.4.